# Intel HAXM is not installing,AVD is not working because of that

Tags: android

[Vt-X is enable click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiIlu.jpg)[Click here to check the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBY9K.jpg)

I use Android Studio and I wanted to use the emulator. I installed HAXM and my error is : /dev/kvm is not found. 
I tried to install HAXM without Android Studio and I have two errors : -
 **During the installation : Failed to configure driver : unknown error. Failed to open driver.
 And after Windows says :  Windows has blocked the installation of an numerically unsigned driver** . Uninstall the program or device who use it and search a numerically signed version of the driver on the editor's website.

I already downloaded HAXM from Intel official site but got same error message.

I hope you can help me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable driver signature enforcement for installing driver so reboot in that mode and try to install.

But you do not need HAXM, add emulator with arm image or install genymotion.

Comment: how to disable driver signature enforcement in windows 10? Thanks .

Comment: Basically genymotion is also not working because of same virtual problem..

Answer (score 1):

I found It!

I faced this problem.I got the solution too.It will work.

**Step 1**: Go to your BIOS settings and check that INTERNET VIRTUAL TECHNOLOGY is Enabled or Disabled.

And make sure HYPER V is disabled.
 To disable it :
 a)Go to Control Panel
 b)Click on Programs(Uninstall a Program)
 c)Then click on Turn Windows features on or off , then look for HYPER-V and untick it. And Restart.
If disabled then enable it.

**Step 2**: Try to install Intel HAXM now and restart. If It shows same problem again.
go to Step 3.

**Step 3**: You have to disable Digitally Signed Enforcement. To disable it permanently  you have to make sure that Secure Boot option is disabled in your system.

**How to check ?**

**Answer is given in the following link. I found it in Internet.**[Thanks whoever made that blog]

link : http://www.windowspasswordsrecovery.com/win8-tips/how-to-disable-uefi-secure-boot-in-windows-8-1-8.html

Step 4: Now restart again.

***To disable driver signature enforcement permanently in Windows 10, you need to do the following:***

1.Open an elevated command prompt instance.
2.Type/paste the following text:

```
     bcdedit.exe /set nointegritychecks on
```

Windows 10 disable driver signature enforcement

Restart Windows 10.

*If you somehow want to enable it again:

1.Type/paste the following text:

```
     bcdedit.exe /set nointegritychecks off
```